# Windows 10 - How to execute a ps1 file on the Remote Desktop instance closing

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop

I remote my PC from another PC/Laptop, because of some reasons I need to execute some Powershell command lines on the remote desktop instance closing.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: After or before closing the session?

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing along below lines

```
$a = Get-Process -name mstsc 

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $a -EventName exited -Action {

Start-Process notepad

}
```

In the start-process, keep your ps1 file

Below are the events , you can subscribe to

[image]

**References:**
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-playing-with-powershell-processes-and-events/

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar, I want to execute that PowerShell script on the host side not on client side, do you know how to detect the remote desktop session was closed?

Comment: you mean on your local laptop/desktop

Comment: No, I want to execute that file on the PC where I am remoting to

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, we have that option in Task Scheduler -> Trigger -> Begin the task = "On disconnect from user"

Comment: Won't trigger that one too, if you log off a normal desktop session?